# How can I use native iOS/Android maps in Ionic Application?

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework, maps

I'm developing an Ionic app that allows the user to select a point of interest and edit the data. To do so, I need to display a map. I've tried using Google Maps, Leaflet, Bing Maps and they work fine (some are a little bit laggy) but a co-worker warned me that the performance would get worse if I started showing all the markers. (I know that I can use plugins to cluster, but thats not the point).
My supervisor said that it would be better if I used native mobile maps. When the app is launched in Android, the map shown to the user would be the android native map and the same thing for iOS.

Can someone explain if this is even possible? I googled it already but I couldn't find any good alternatives.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a way to achieve this is to detect the platform and use specific code for each :
[PhoneGap - Detect device type in phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077853/phonegap-detect-device-type-in-phonegap)

(Ionic is based on phonegap/cordova)

You can also develop a cordova plugin who use differents API from each platform. There is already a cordova plugin for maps, but who only works on ios and android, and only with google map :

https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps

Hope this help

Comment: Unfortunately I had to change the way of thinking. Ionic and Phonegap doesn't work very well with maps because the performance its not very good (bad memory management).
Im developing my app naively.

Thanks anyways!